# How to implement a horizontal card style

Tags: html, css

So I need to implement a card style like this: http://prntscr.com/p6svjf

What's the best way of doing this to make sure it is responsive?

```
<div class="recent-work">
    <img src="work/mercedes.png">
    <h3>Modern website conecept</h3>
    <p>This is a problem</p>
</div>
```

```
.recent-work {
    background-color: black;
    width           : 100%;
    height          : 50%;
    padding-top     : 10%;
}

.recent-work img {
    width: 750px;
}

.recent-work p {
    color  : white;
    display: inline;
}

.recent-work h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: I would look into Flexbox if you can. Boostrap 4 uses Flexbox and is a great, responsive framework.

Keep your elements relative for the most part and use media queries to target different device widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox to divide the card into two parts and work separately with each

**Example**

```css
.recent-work {
  display: flex;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: black;
}

.recent-work .pic {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 40%
}

.pic img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.recent-work p {
  color: white;
  display: inline;
}

.desc {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.recent-work h1 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .recent-work {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .desc {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="recent-work">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354">
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <h1>Modern website conecept</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi reiciendis suscipit repudiandae, exercitationem perferendis eligendi. Saepe, nesciunt explicabo! Maxime deserunt necessitatibus perferendis nesciunt ratione est nihil voluptatum doloremque
      fugit ipsam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/bGbjPVz)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I can change the responsiveness in the @media so once It reaches a specific width the text should align underneath the image?

Comment: @Ruan, Sure. Updated code. You can check